# PHP Load Dynamic File To String (CSS FIle Generate)

Tags: php, css, string, load

`file_get_contents()` was not the right way to do this...

I want to load a PHP script so that it runs, and write the output to a CSS file.

How is that done?

Comment: Would you mind to further improve your question..

Comment: elaborate your question with more information

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

```
ob_start();
// Prepare and assign your code in $data variable
echo $data;
$content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($file_path, $content);
```